# OSError: libcudart.so.9.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: cuda, mxnet

trying to run a script, when i get

```
(infacepytorch) ryan@ryan-7570:/media/ryan/shakira/InsightFace_Pytorch$ python face_verify.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_verify.py", line 9, in <module>
from Learner import face_learner
  File "/media/ryan/shakira/InsightFace_Pytorch/Learner.py", line 1, in <module>
    from data.data_pipe import de_preprocess, get_train_loader, get_val_data
  File "/media/ryan/shakira/InsightFace_Pytorch/data/data_pipe.py", line 12, in <module>
import mxnet as mx
  File "/home/ryan/virtualenvs/infacepytorch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mxnet/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from .context import Context, current_context, cpu, gpu, cpu_pinned
  File "/home/ryan/virtualenvs/infacepytorch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mxnet/context.py", line 24, in <module>
from .base import classproperty, with_metaclass, _MXClassPropertyMetaClass
  File "/home/ryan/virtualenvs/infacepytorch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mxnet/base.py", line 213, in <module>
_LIB = _load_lib()
  File "/home/ryan/virtualenvs/infacepytorch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mxnet/base.py", line 204, in _load_lib
lib = ctypes.CDLL(lib_path[0], ctypes.RTLD_LOCAL)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 347, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libcudart.so.9.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64 && sudo ldconfig
```

but i still get the same error,
Any suggestions would be really helpfull, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your learning framework clearly needs CUDA 9.2 not CUDA 9.0. Install it

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by talonmies you're running a version of MXNet that depends on Cuda-9.2. It would be preferable to install Cuda-9.2 and update your library path to point to 9.2.

You can also also install MXNet for 9.0 using the pip package `mxnet-cu90` if you were unable to update your Cuda dependencies.